# Unable to get NSL-KDD datasets

Tags: data-mining

The link provided for NSL-KDD datasets is from http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/
However, I am not able to access the website.
I need the data for my dissertation. I am trying to train it in a neural network for intrusion detection system.
Is there any other way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be available via the Way Back Machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150205070216/http://nsl.cs.unb.ca/NSL-KDD/

The ARFF and Text files containing the dataset are available within the links.